# How much information do I need for a Lorentz transformation?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation

If I use Lorentz transformations,
\begin{align}
x' &= \gamma (x-vt), \\
t' &=\gamma \left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right),
\end{align}
I need $x,v,t$ to calculate $x'$ and $t'$. If I only know, say for example, $x$ and proper time $t'$, I can calculate the relative velocity of the frames, $x'$ and $t$ by using length contraction and $v=x/t=x'/t'$. But how do I derive these quantities directly with Lorentz transformation? Is this possible? Even if I try to use the constant space-time-distance, it doesn't work out. In general I'm confused why Lorentz transformations are so important because it seems to me like one can calculate the same things with less effort by length contraction and time dilatation?

Comment: I don't really understand why this question is phrased as if length contraction/time dilation and Lorentz transformations are somehow distinct things. Time dilation/length contraction are just the results of applying a Lorentz transformation!

Comment: _"If I only know, say for example,  and proper time ′"_ - you know $x$ and proper time $t'$ of WHAT? Which physics problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am not trying to solve a physics problem, I am just confused when I should use Lorentz transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In general I'm confused why Lorentz transformations are so important because it seems to me like one can calculate the same things with less effort by length contraction and time dilatation?

This is not correct. The Lorentz transformations include length contraction, time dilation, and the relativity of simultaneity. Most of the so-called "paradoxes" of SR center around the relativity of simultaneity. So if you use only length contraction and time dilation then you will get most of the "paradoxes" wrong.

The Lorentz transform is an essential tool for SR, and (in my opinion) the simplified length contraction and time dilation formulas should be avoided for new students. They frequently misuse them and there is no need for them since they automatically drop out of the Lorentz transform whenever appropriate.

> I can calculate the relative velocity of the frames, x′ and t by using length contraction and v=x/t=x′/t′.

No, in general it is not true that $v=x/t$. If you happen to know that it is true for a specific scenario then you can use that fact also, but you cannot assume it in general.

In general, it depends on what you want to know. You have two equations in 5 variables ($c$ is not a variable and $\gamma$ is just a function of $v$ so it isn't an independent variable). So if you want to determine the coordinates of a specific single event $(t',x')$ then you need three pieces of information. However, if you only want to determine, for example, the coordinates of a worldline $(t',f(t'))$ then you may only need two.

Of course, the problem itself may introduce new unknowns such as equations of motion or other new variables. There is thus no one universal answer to the question.

Small nitpick: the $t'$ used in the Lorentz transform is not proper time, it is just coordinate time in the primed frame.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Why is $v=x/t=x'/t'$ in general not correct, because I thought the relative velocity between two frames is equal when determined from those frames? And is it an extra piece of information if one knows that t is proper time?

Comment: @Quaeram Neither t’ nor t are proper time. They are both coordinate time in their respective reference frames. You cannot assume $v=x/t$ because you aren’t always interested in the worldline of something through the origin moving at v. You might be interested in something at rest: $x=x_0$ or something moving sinusoidal $x= \cos(t)$. And if you are interested in $v=x/t$ then you will get $x’/t’=0\ne v$

Answer (score 0):

The direct Lorentz transformations are :
$$ \begin{cases} x'=\gamma \left(x-vt\right)\;\;\;\;\;(1)\\  t'=\gamma \left(t-\frac{v}{c^{2}}x\right)\;\;\;\;(2)\end{cases}$$

(1) and (2) gives $$\begin{cases}v=(x-\gamma^{-1}x')/t\;\;\;\;\;(1')\\\\v=(t-\gamma^{-1}t')c^{2}/x\;\;\;\;(2') \end{cases}$$

To be rigorous, we have to work with differences, i.e. with
$$\begin{cases}v=(\Delta x-\gamma^{-1}\Delta x')/\Delta t\\v=(\Delta t-\gamma^{-1}\Delta t')c^{2}/\Delta x \end{cases}$$
but as usual we pose: $t=t'=0$ in $x'=x=0$ , which does not change anything to calculate v directly.

we can see that the equation (2) is only the equation (1) for the light, i.e. $x'=ct'$ and $x=ct$ !!!* ,so $\;\frac{x'}{t'}=\frac{x}{t}=c$

(2') becomes $$v=(x/c-\gamma^{-1}t')c^{2}/x $$
with (x,t') as data, and the unknowns (t,x') follow from the relation $t=x/c \;,\; x'=ct'$

(*) In reality, it's so that $\;x'^{2}-ct'^{2}=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $ x'-ct'=0\;$ or $\;x'+ct'=0$ and $\;x^{2}-ct^{2}=0$.....

Comment: Thanks! Do I understand this right: you "use light-flashes to measure distances"? Or does (*) only apply to light-like intervals? And my relation, $v=x/t=x'/t'$, is certainly wrong, isn't it?

Comment: All measurements in special relativity (space or time) are related to the one of light, that's why we talk about Einstein synchronization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation

Comment: If v=x'/t'=x/t, the relation: x'²-c²t'²=x²-c²t²=0 is not verified for v<c .